# A tool like ReSharper, but for Java?

Tags: java, resharper

I have read a lot about ReSharper on here.  It sounds like it has a lot of cool features to help the programmer out.  Trouble is, I don't write C#.

Is there any tool that has similar functionality to ReSharper, but for Java instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Heh, five answers, almost at the same time.

Comment: don't know why jetbrains don't release a plugin for eclipse that provides all the intelliJ refactorings

Comment: maybe they want people to buy their intelliJ IDE instead

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) an IDE from JetBrains - the creator of ReSharper.
It's not "like resharper" - it's the original and resharper is like it for C#.

Comment: The PO specifially asked for a tool like resharper, not another IDE. His requirements are to use the IDE he is comfortable with, but with all improvements and detections intellij systems provide.

Comment: It seems like that was what he was looking for. In any case even an extension needs to run inside an IDE

Comment: JetBrains offers comprehensive Student educational license. just to be said

Answer (score 22):

I believe most Java IDEs already have it - I certainly view ReSharper as [the tool which brings Visual Studio up to the level of Eclipse](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/archive/2007/03/27/visual-studio-2005-vs-eclipse-again-but-this-time-with-resharper) :)

Do you have any specific R# features in mind?

Comment: I'd consider IntelliJ to be a long way past Eclipse - JMO.  I've used both, and it's no contest.

Comment: So I've been led to believe, but having tried IntelliJ a few times I haven't got "into" it yet. I gather it would be helpful to have a knowledgeable user next to me when using it... it just hasn't happened yet.

Comment: ReSharper brings VS to a level of IDEA which is higher than level of Eclipse, in my opinion.

Comment: @Jon, it seems the link to your blog is broken. I couldn't load it. The same for few other links to your blog in your other answers.

Comment: @nawfal: Yes, my blog is currently moving/down. I'm not sure whether we'll end up with the old links working - but I'll definitely have a different canonical address soonish. When that's sorted, I'll probably write something using the SO API to fetch all my answers, editing those that refer to the blog.

Comment: could someone tell me where the option is in intellij

Answer (score 11):

Resharper was developed by JetBrains and is a port of [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) functionality to C#

Answer (score 6):

Use NetBeans IDE, this IDE has all functionality of the ReSharper and the most important, they are natively in the IDE.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/, a Java IDE made by Jetbrains, the Resharper creator.

It's not an addin to an IDE, but it is a excellent IDE itself. Most features (if not all) that you can found in ReSharper are in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4):

ReSharper is a Visual Studio tool, not a language tool. The closest equivalent would be [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html), from the people who created ReSharper.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall it correctly resharper are just the extra features that Intellj (the jetbrains ide) has by default for java