# Tools for refactoring?

Tags: java, netbeans, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I use netbeans on my work and find that some things are hard to do refactoring. What tools do you recommend for me?

Comment: What refactorings do you want to do?  Things like "rename" are widely available and nearly foolproof.  Other refactorings, like "extract class", are more difficult to do well and less common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this thread:
[Java refactoring tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708164/java-refactoring-tools)

Answer (score 3):

[IntellJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/refactoring.html) has always had excellent refactoring support.