# Getting declaring class in Java

Tags: java, class

Having something like in Java:

```
class A {}
class B {private A a;}
class C {private A a;}
```

How could I know which is the class that declared a ?

I.e. I want to get class B or class C

Any ideas are appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Weird requirement. The only thing I can think of is passing the value as a parameter to the `a` objects, either in its constructor or as a private attribute. Nothing in the JVM would provide you this info.

Comment: *"Getting declaring class in Java"*  Use a debugger?  Why would this be needed in production code?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do... You want ALL classes running in the JVM that have an attribute of class A? Why do you want this?

Comment: Why you want to know which is the class that declared a ?

Comment: Maybe you want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A {
    public void print(){
        String className = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
        System.out.println(className);
    }
}
class A1 {
    private A a;
    public A1(){
        a= new A();
        a.print();
    }
}
class A2 {
    private A a;
    public A2(){
        a= new A();
        a.print();
    }
}
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A1 a1= new A1();
        A2 a2 = new A2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ;learn how to use code formatting.  Select the code and click the `{}` button above the message preparation form.

Comment: I was thinking better of Thread.currentThread().getStrackTrace() instead of throwing the exception. Both work equally good.

Comment: Thanx Andrew, i will try this next time. :)

Answer (score 5):

You couldn't just with the structure you've specified. You'd have to pass a reference to an instance of `B` or `C` into `A`'s constructor, then write some logic to determine the type passed in.

Answer (score 2):

As i understand the question you need to find all usages of class A (type usages) in your code (Please correct me if i'm wrong).

It depend on your IDE and the installed plugins for code inspection, most IDE's provide such a functionality, in Eclipse for example you can right click a Class and select "References->Project"

And if your IDE does not have this there are alot of tools for java, take a look at: [A tool like ReSharper, but for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615334/a-tool-like-resharper-but-for-java)

Comment: in Java, using Eclipse, you can right click a Class and select "References->Project". I'm not sure if the question was about runtime or not...

Answer (score 2):

You have to do someting like:

```
class A {

    boolean itWasC;

    public A( C objectC ) {
        itWasC = true;
    }

    public A( B objectB ) {
        itWasC = false;
    }
}
```

And once you create an object of class "A" from `class B` or `class C` pass `this` to the constructor. For example: `A objectA = new A( this )`
It is weird, and **you can't do it without instanciating objects**.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that in java  unless you have a reference of the Object in Class A... definitely not through programatically nor in runtime.

But if you just want to find out the classes that are referencing Class A , one option is to rename the class to something else and try to compile.

And Voila , compiler would list all the classes that Reference Class A , but cannot resolve to a type.

Another alternative ,would be to use [Reflections to find out the Variables in a Class](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html) and compare if the type of the variable is of Class A type

Heres a sample Program i wrote to do just that

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import com.test.ClassA;

```
 package com.test;
    public class ClassA {

   }



    public class ClassB {

        private ClassA classA;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception,
                NoSuchFieldException {

            Field classVariable = ClassB.class
                    .getDeclaredField("classA");

            classVariable.setAccessible(true);

            System.out.println(classVariable.getType());

            System.out.println(ClassA.class);

            if (ClassA.class.equals(classVariable.getType())) {
                System.out.println("Class A is referenced");
            }

        }
    }
```

**Result**

```
class com.test.ClassA
class com.test.ClassA
Class A is referenced
```